# Archive failed but new WAL never generated

Tags: postgresql, performance, replication, postgresql-12, write-ahead-logging

Currently I am experiencing a weird situation. Archive `failed_count` soaring from 0 to 2475.

Here some parameter that I check :

1. select * from pg_stat_archiver;

`archived_count` 3567;
`last_archived_time` 2022-08-17 21:36:05;
`failed_count` 2516;
`last_failed_time` 2022-08-18 10:58

2. `select pg_switch_wal();`
   WAL is always switching, very 1- 2 second.
3. SELECT pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), replay_lsn)
   FROM pg_stat_replication;

This is changing too every second. Always rotating from thousands to 0 over period of time.

4. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_ls_dir('pg_wal') WHERE pg_ls_dir ~ '^[0-9A-F]{24}';`

Since 12 am this morning, this value was always 7450. Before that, it always increased. Maximum value observed was 10811

5. `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_bgwriter ;`
   This gives out :

   Name                 |Value                        |
   ---------------------+-----------------------------+
   checkpoints_timed    |109040 --> increasing        |
   checkpoints_req      |96 --> stay the same         |
   checkpoint_write_time|12514471288                  |
   checkpoint_sync_time |1373072.0                    |
   buffers_checkpoint   |412734838                    |
   buffers_clean        |20745183                     |
   maxwritten_clean     |121362                       |
   buffers_backend      |98238043                     |
   buffers_backend_fsync|0                            |
   buffers_alloc        |904724994                    |
   stats_reset          |2021-08-04 12:19:41.333 +0700|

Looking at `pg_stat_bgwriter`, checkpoints_timed is increasing, which is good.

This happens to just my production servers (the other one is testing server).

- Whats going on ?  Why WAL stop generating but the archived count is failing ? I am under impression that if there is no new WAL then the archiving should not take place.
- What LOGGING parameter I should turn on to monitor these errors ?

My configuration :

```
name                        |setting                                   |unit|
----------------------------+------------------------------------------+----+
archive_command             |test ! -f /archive/%f && cp %p /archive/%f|    |
archive_mode                |on                                        |    |
archive_timeout             |2400                                      |s   |
checkpoint_completion_target|0.9                                       |    |
checkpoint_flush_after      |32                                        |8kB |
checkpoint_timeout          |300                                       |s   |
checkpoint_warning          |30                                        |s   |
hot_standby                 |on                                        |    |
log_checkpoints             |off                                       |    |
max_replication_slots       |10                                        |    |
max_wal_senders             |5                                         |    |
max_wal_size                |8192                                      |MB  |
min_wal_size                |2048                                      |MB  |
synchronous_commit          |off                                       |    |
synchronous_standby_names   |*                                         |    |
wal_compression             |off                                       |    |
wal_keep_segments           |4000                                      |    |
wal_level                   |logical                                   |    |
wal_log_hints               |off                                       |    |
wal_segment_size            |16777216                                  |B   |
wal_sender_timeout          |60000                                     |ms  |
```

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL keeps trying to archive the same WAL segment again and again. That is why the number of failures keeps increasing, even if no new WAL is generated.

Fix the problem – the error messages in the PostgreSQL log should give you a clue concerning the cause.

Comment: which parameter i should turn on for logging ? thanks @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Logging happens automatically. Check the PostgreSQL server log .